# Joining two lists in linq and return consolidated records

Tags: c#, linq

Currently, the return type is:

> "System.Collections.GenericList<{a:ConsoleApplication3.Person,b:ConsoleApplication3.Person>

What is the best way to get the `List<Person>` with all the data just like the SQL join would return? 
I want to get only two rows in the `List<Person>` :

```
{Name:Jon, Address=loc1,Country=US,Continent=NA} 

{Name:Ryan, Address=loc2,Country=Germany,Continent=Europe}
```

---

```
Person person1 = new Person();
person1.Name = "Jon";
person1.Address = "loc1";

Person person2 = new Person();
person2.Name = "Ryan";
person2.Address = "loc2";

Person person3 = new Person();
person3.Name = "Jon";
person3.Country = "US";
person3.Continent = "NA";

Person person4 = new Person();
person4.Name="Ryan";
person4.Country = "Germany";
person4.Continent = "Europe";

list1.Add(person1);
list1.Add(person2);

list2.Add(person3);
list2.Add(person4);

var  result = (from a in list1 
               join b in list2 on a.Name equals b.Name 
               select new {a,b}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Firstly** you should create a new `Person`. So your query should be like this:

```
var resulttt = (from a in list1
                join b in list2 on a.Name equals b.Name
                select new Person
                {
                    Name = a.Name,
                    Address = a.Address ?? b.Address,
                    Country = a.Country ?? b.Country,
                    Continent = a.Continent ?? b.Continent
                }).ToList();
```

**Secondly** to show the result in the correct format and as you want you need to override the `ToString` method like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Continent { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("Name = {0}, Address = {1}, Country = {2}, Continent = {3}", Name,Address,Country,Continent);
    }
}
```

**Finally** by iterating through the result you will get your desired result. Like this:

```
foreach (var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);                
}
```

Output:

> Name:Jon, Address=loc1,Country=US,Continent=NA
>
> Name:Ryan, Address=loc2,Country=Germany,Continent=Europe

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to create new objects

```
var results = (from a in list1 
               join b in list2 on a.Name equals b.Name 
               select new Person
               { 
                   Name = a.Name,  
                   Address = a.Address,  
                   Country = b.Country,  
                   Continent = b.Continent
               }).ToList();
```

If however you don't know which list has values you could do something like the following

```
var results = (from a in list1 
               join b in list2 on a.Name equals b.Name 
               select new Person
               { 
                   Name = a.Name,  
                   Address = a.Address ?? b.Address,  
                   Country = a.Country ?? b.Country,  
                   Continent = a.Continent ?? b.Continent
               }).ToList();
```

That will take the values from `list1` unless they are `null` and if they are it will instead take the values from `list2`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really get how you're choosing whether the Country is in the first list of the second one. But you can do something like this:

```
var  result = (from a in list1 
               join b in list2 on a.Name equals b.Name 
               select new Person()
               {
                  Name = a.Name,
                  Address = a.Address
                  Country = b.Country ?? a.Country  
                  Continent = b.Continent ?? a.Continent 
               }).ToList();
```

You can play with the conditions however you want and maybe even mix them to have multi-level conditions on both a and b.

Answer (score 0):

You want a Tuple:

```
List<Tuple<Person, Person>> result = (
from a in list1
join b in list2 on a.Name equals b.Name
select Tuple.Create(a, b)
).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If List 1 always has Address and List 2 always has Country and Continent, your linq statement would look something like

```
var  result = (from a in list1 join b in list2 on a.Name equals b.Name select new Person { Name = a.Name, Address = a.Address, Country = b.Country, Continent = b.Continent }).ToList();
```